# Convert row data to column data in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

For example: There is a table of one column is having data like `common` and I want to display it as

```
c
o
m
m
o
n
```

Comment: You need to be more clear see this topic https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the posted sample data this'll do ya:

```
select substr(col1, level, 1)
from t23
connect by level <= length(col1)
/
```

If your real need is more complicated then you must post a realistic use case. If you simply have more than one row of data in your table then MT0's [recursive WITH clause solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46543116/146325) is the way to go (assuming you are on 11gR2 or higher)

Comment: This will not work if there is more than one row in the table (the hierarchical query will create exponential numbers of duplicate rows as there is nothing to restrict the association of each level of the hierarchy to only its parent so it will associate it with all possible parents creating many, many duplicates).

Comment: @MT0 - your comment is quite correct. That's why I prefaced my answer with *For the posted sample data* :)

Comment: @APC: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c3fe2/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name( value ) AS
SELECT 'common' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'string' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         value,
         '(.)',
         '\1' || CHR(10)
       )
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c3fe2/4/0)**:

```
| REGEXP_REPLACE(VALUE,'(.)','\1'||CHR(10)) |
|-------------------------------------------|
| c                                         |
| o                                         |
| m                                         |
| m                                         |
| o                                         |
| n                                         |
|                                           |
| s                                         |
| t                                         |
| r                                         |
| i                                         |
| n                                         |
| g                                         |
|                                           |
```

(Use `TRIM` to remove the trailing newline if you need to.)

**Query 2**:

```
WITH characters ( value, character, lvl ) AS (
  SELECT value, SUBSTR( value, 1, 1 ), 1 FROM table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT value, SUBSTR( value, lvl + 1, 1 ), lvl + 1
  FROM   characters
  WHERE  lvl < LENGTH( value )
)
SELECT character
FROM   characters
ORDER BY value, lvl
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c3fe2/4/1)**:

```
| CHARACTER |
|-----------|
|         c |
|         o |
|         m |
|         m |
|         o |
|         n |
|         s |
|         t |
|         r |
|         i |
|         n |
|         g |
```

Comment: The first solution doesn't produce multiple rows, it fakes them with newlines. But the recursive WITH solution works well.

Comment: @APC The OP is unclear as to their requirements when they say "I want to display it as ...". They could want each character in a separate row or they could just want each character on a newline in the same row (both give the output the OP posted).